# How to add arrows on Networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have made a graph with `networkx` lib in Python.
Now I want to add arrows on the lines on the graph, but It seams that I am doing something wrong. This is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

analysis_graph = nx.Graph()
# I have also tried with DiGraph() but it still does not work

node_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

analysis_graph.add_nodes_from(node_list)
#print(analysis_graph.nodes())

nx.draw(analysis_graph, with_labels = True)
relation_list = [['A', 'B'],
                 ['A', 'C'],
                 ['B', 'D'],
                 ['C', 'E'],
                 ['D', 'F'],
                 ['E', 'D'],
                 ['C', 'E'],
                 ['B', 'D'],                 
                 ['C', 'F'],
                 ['A', 'E'],
                 ['B', 'C'],                 
                 ['B', 'F'],
                 ['D', 'A']]

analysis_graph = nx.from_edgelist(relation_list)
print(nx.info(analysis_graph))
nx.draw(analysis_graph, with_labels = True, arrowsize=20, arrowstyle='fancy')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw arrows, the graph apparently does have to be a `DiGraph` object.
If I change the following line:

```
analysis_graph = nx.from_edgelist(relation_list)
```

to

```
analysis_graph = nx.from_edgelist(relation_list, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

I do get the desired output.

[image]

Your previous attempt to instantiate a `DiGraph` object in line 2 (ignoring blanks)

```
analysis_graph = nx.DiGraph()
```

had no effect, as you are overwriting the `analysis_graph` object when calling `nx.from_edgelist`. What you probably meant to write was

```
analysis_graph = nx.DiGraph()
analysis_graph.add_nodes_from(nodelist)
analysis_graph.add_edges_from(relation_list)
```

Comment: Do you know why my .Graph() is different compared to .DiGraph()?
Im not talking about arrows, but the total look is different

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "total look". I would suggest yost a new question with some examples.

Comment: Please check it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314656/different-graph-with-networkx-in-python-when-arrows-are-used