# Different Graph with Networkx in Python when arrows are used

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I wrote a code that plots a network with `Networkx` lib in Python.
My code works good, but I'm confused with one thing.
I get totally different looks of the graphs when I use `.Graph()` and `.DiGraph()`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# defining graph
analysis_graph = nx.Graph()
#analysis_graph = nx.DiGraph()

# defining relations
relation_list = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'E'], ['C', 'F'], ['F', 'I'], ['F', 'H'], ['F', 'G'], ['F', 'J']]

# adding relations to the graph
analysis_graph.add_edges_from(relation_list)

# extracting nodes from relations
node_list = nx.nodes(analysis_graph)


# ADDING COLORS TO GRAPH

# defining colors for each node
colors = {"red": ["A", "B", "C"], "green": ["D", "E", "F"], "yellow": ["G", "H", "I", 'J']}
# Create a mapping of node -> color from `colors`:
node_color_map = {}
for color, nodes in colors.items():
    node_color_map.update(dict.fromkeys(nodes, color))
node_color_list = [node_color_map.get(node) for node in node_list]
print(node_color_map)
print(node_color_list)

# For getting node sizes
dict_of_node_sizes = dict(analysis_graph.degree) # for getting node sizes
print(dict_of_node_sizes)

# for giving same graph each time
my_pos = nx.spring_layout(analysis_graph, seed = 0) 

print(nx.info(analysis_graph))
plt.figure(figsize=(25,17))
nx.draw(analysis_graph, 
        pos = my_pos, 
        with_labels = True, 
        arrowsize=20, 
        font_size=12, 
        node_size=[(v+1) * 150 for v in dict_of_node_sizes.values()],
        node_color=node_color_list)
```

These are the results, with arrows is `.DiGraph()` and without is `.Graph()`:

[image]

[image]

Is there a chance to get the same shape of the graph with and without arrows?

Comment: The seed in `nx.spring_layout` is not working as intended, so your simplest option is to save out the positions, and then load and reuse them when you are plotting the second graph. The reason why the seed is probably not working is that in the undirected `Graph` object edges are counted double when computing the attraction between connected nodes, whereas in the `DiGraph` edges are counted only once. So the seed is potentially working (not 100% on that as there used to be issues) but the forces are definitely different and hence the outcome of the spring layout is different.

Comment: Ok, but how can I fix this problem?
Can you post an answer with code example?

Comment: What would you consider a solution to the problem?  The suggestion about calculating the positions once and using it for both plots seems reasonable.  If that's not a solution, can you explain what would be a solution?

Comment: my nodes and relations between nodes will change each hour, so I do not think that calculation will work. FYI I do not know how to calculate that.
Is there a way to update my code so that I can get graph with arrows that will look the same as graph without arrows?
So, it does not matter if i use .Graph() or .DiGraph(), shape of my graph should remain the same